# Blockchain's previous snapshot

Tags: blockchain, full-node

Is there any way to download past btc transactions without running a full node?
Searching about this, usually all the answers suggest to run a full node. I.e. I want a file that contains, say, all the transactions up to 2020.

Answer (score 2):

The standard answer to this still is, and will likely remain, to run a full node. Not only will you be able to download the entire blockchain this way, but you can also be sure it hasn't been tampered with.

There are services that allow you to download specific parts of the blockchain, for example [Blockchair](https://blockchair.com/dumps). However, for a dataset as large as "all transactions up to 2020" there really isn't a good reason not to download it through a full node, and you will have it ready for whatever blockchain data you might want to analyze next time.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can download a block chain bootstrap file.

Those files were popular years ago, until they were ditched at some point, related to the full nodes max decentralization narrative.

You can download a block chain bootstrap, and if it's not tampered, your node will finish synchronizing and keep synchronized.

However, nobody is creating such bootstrap files anymore, as far as I am aware.

So, as others have pointed out correctly, synchronize your node from genesis. It'll take some time, but it'll be fun.

Comment: "related to the full nodes max decentralization narrative." Never heard that before and also false: wouldn't matter where it comes from as long as you run a fully validating nodes. Reason was simply that bitcoin core can download it faster than bittorrent would. And it's also faster when looking at total time of download+validate, as core van do that in parallel while any other download alternative can not.

Comment: Is there any place, any scenario, where driving to town with a drive, downloading a bootstrap to the drive in an Internet cafe, then driving back home, verify the drive blocks, is faster or cheaper than downloading the whole chain from home?